# How do I detect if I'm running MATLAB or Octave?

Tags: matlab, portability, octave

I need to write code that should run equally well in Octave and on MATLAB. Problem is that it needs to do some GUI stuff, which MATLAB and Octave handle completely differently.

Is there a way I can detect if I'm running MATLAB or Octave, in order to call the right function?

Answer (score 56):

You could use the following test to differentiate Octave from MATLAB:

```
isOctave = exist('OCTAVE_VERSION', 'builtin') ~= 0;
```

Comment: Good call, though it would be better encapsulated in a function.

Comment: Hm. exist('OCTAVE_VERSION', 'builtin') evaluates to 0 on both matlab and octave for me :-( . And I upvoted this answer before checking, whoops.

Comment: @foobarbecue works just fine (just tried [it](https://octave-online.net/)), the same test is even included in the official Octave manual: https://octave.org/doc/latest/How-to-Distinguish-Between-Octave-and-Matlab.html

Comment: Hm, must have been something funky going on with my environment. Works now.

Answer (score 24):

There is also a [hint](http://octave.org/wiki/index.php?title=Compatibility) in the wiki on the official octave.org website. 
They propose the following:

Edit: Not all versions of Matlab support '#' for comments so I changed the example to use '%' instead. It works in Matlab R2018 (Linux) and Octave 4.2.2

```
function foo
  %% fancy code that works in both
  if (is_octave)
    %% use octave super_powers
  else
    %% do it matlab way
  end
  %% fancy code that works in both
end

%% subfunction that checks if we are in octave
function r = is_octave ()
  persistent x;
  if (isempty (x))
    x = exist ('OCTAVE_VERSION', 'builtin');
  end
  r = x;
end
```

Comment: @Spoonless: “R2018“ is not a MATLAB version. This should be either R2018a or R2018b.

Answer (score 5):

I would use, for example, the ver command, which yields:

in MATLAB:

---

MATLAB Version 7.7.0.471 (R2008b)
   Operating System: Linux 2.6.31-20-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 8 09:05:19 UTC 2010 i686
   Java VM Version: Java 1.6.0_04 with Sun Microsystems Inc. Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM mixed mode

---

in Octave:

---

GNU Octave Version 3.0.5
  GNU Octave License: GNU General Public License
  Operating System: Linux 2.6.31-20-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 8 09:05:19 UTC 2010 i686

---

Another possibility is to use the license function.

Answer (score 4):

In Matlab:

```
>> exist __octave_config_info__
ans =
     0
```

In Octave:

```
octave:3> exist __octave_config_info__
ans =  5
```

Comment: That's exist('octave_config_info') in an if statement for the Octave syntactically challenged (like me)...

Comment: Actually, I get `ans = 0` on **both Matlab and Octave** for this command!

Comment: @winkmal try the `exist  __octave_config_info__` instead. the `octave_config_info` is obsolete. More info [here](https://github.com/octave-app/octave-app/issues/141)