# Ignore certain lines in Octave (but keep them for Matlab)

Tags: matlab, octave, environment, getenv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I detect if I’m running MATLAB or Octave?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246579/how-do-i-detect-if-im-running-matlab-or-octave)

My code was designed using MATLAB and I still use it.  However, if I try to run some parts of it using Octave, I get errors.  For example, MATLAB code uses `pause on` which Octave doesn't.

Is there a way to check which programming environment is using the code?  For example,

```
if  invoking_env == 'Matlab'
    % do this
else 
    % ok, so do this
end
```

I can use `getenv('COMPUTERNAME')` but in this case the computer name is the same!  Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is version function both in [MATLAB](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/version.html) and [Octave](http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/version.html). They return different values and MATLAB's version have some arguments, that are absent in Octave. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks.  I went ahead with `A=ver; isequal (A(1,2).Name, 'MATLAB')`

Comment: better use [strcmpi](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/strcmpi.html) for comparing strings

Answer (score 0):

I think the best method is to have a sub function that checks this. The following snippet is probably the one that requires the minimum from the system. And with the persistent variable it can be called repeatedly without a heavy performance hit.

```
function r = isoctave ()
  persistent x;
  if (isempty (x))
    x = exist ('OCTAVE_VERSION', 'builtin');
  end
  r = x;
end
```

You can then use it easily in condition blocks. See [that entry](http://wiki.octave.org/Compatibility) on the Octave wiki.